# Cocos2d-x AppDelegate data member initialization lost

Tags: c++, initialization, cocos2d-x

Consider the following class declaration

```
class AppDelegate : private cocos2d::Application
{
private:
  int _test;
  // ....
};
```

I'm initializing the data member `int _test` as

```
AppDelegate::AppDelegate() : _test(20) { 
  cocos2d::log("Initialzing %p with _test = %d", this, _test);
}
```

Later, when the code

```
bool AppDelegate::applicationDidFinishLaunching() {
  cocos2d::log("Checking %p, found _test = %d", this, _test);
  // ....
}
```

is executed, the output is

```
Initialzing 0x10da4aa20 with _test = 20
// ....
Checking 0x10da4aa20, found _test = 1056964608
```

This indicates that `_test` is uninitialized. The problem seems to be specific to the cocos2d-x architecture, as I'm not able to reproduce this in a sandbox project (where `AppDelegate` is exchanged for a simpler class).

My question is: why is this initialization lost? Is there another way to initialize and use data member in the `AppDelegate` class?

Comment: Do you have a custom copy-constructor or copy-assignment operator?

Comment: No, no custom copy-constructor or copy-assignment operators.

Comment: I'm not familiar cocos2dx.I remember that every class has a function that name is "init". They are called after constructor. Maybe this function make it...

Comment: That is true for every class inheriting from `cocos2d::node`, however, `AppDelegate : private cocos2d::Application` is generated by a tool. No `init` method in either `AppDelegate` or the parent classes (cocos2d::Application reference http://www.cocos2d-x.org/reference/native-cpp/V3.4/db/de2/classcocos2d_1_1_application.html).

Answer (score 0):

So it turned out that the `_test` data member was changed as the `PhysicsMaterial` constructor was executed:

```
typedef struct CC_DLL PhysicsMaterial
{
    float density;          ///< The density of the object.
    float restitution;      ///< The bounciness of the physics body.
    float friction;         ///< The roughness of the surface of a shape.

    PhysicsMaterial()
    : density(0.0f)
    , restitution(0.0f)
    , friction(0.0f)
    {}

    PhysicsMaterial(float aDensity, float aRestitution, float aFriction)
    : density(aDensity)
    , restitution(aRestitution)
    , friction(aFriction)
    {} // Watch reveals that this was the culprit ...
}PhysicsMaterial;
```

Clearly, there is no code in this constructor that should change the value of the `_test` member, indicating that there was something wrong with the earlier build.

A clean and subsequent full rebuild solved the problem.